# apache solr 6.x with apache nutch 2.3.1

Tags: java, solr, version-control, lucene, nutch

I have to crawl a some webdata using Apache Nutch 2.3.1 and then provide full text facility. For that, I have decided to use Apache Solr 6.1 that is latest stable release. But according to Apache [Nutch site](http://nutch.apache.org/), It is recommended to use Solr 4.10.3 with Apache Nutch 2.3.1.

What is the problem if I use latest Solr version. Nutch have to just index data to solr by REST API. Is there really some problem that can happen if I change the version ?